# Listar dispositivos BLE cercanos android

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, scanner

estoy empezando en el tema de Kotlin y necesito implementar un escáner de BLE devices para una app movil, pero estoy encontrando bastantes quebraderos de cabeza.
En primer lugar dispongo de una funcion scan:

```
fun scan() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {            
        mBluetoothAdapter?.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback)
    } else { 
        mLEScanner = mBluetoothAdapter!!.bluetoothLeScanner
        mLEScanner!!.startScan(mScanCallback)
    }
}
```

Tras la cual implemento un ScanCallback en el cual de momento estoy haciendo pruebas con dos nombres "a pelo" los cuales son Running Speed y EnvSens_Wearable, los cuales si se encuentran y a los que me permite conectarme correctamente y descubrir sus servicios correctamente, mi problema viene en el momento en el que quiero obtener la lista completa de todos los elementos escaneados en el proceso, desconozco si existe alguna lista o función que los pueda mostrar por defecto.

```
private val mScanCallback = object : ScanCallback() {
    override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult) {
        mLeDevice = result.device

        if(mLeDevice?.name == "Running Speed" || mLeDevice?.name == "EnvSens_Wearable"){
            globalAdress = mLeDevice!!.address
            globalName = mLeDevice!!.name
            mLEScanner!!.stopScan(this)
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_BLESCAN_CALLBACK)
        } else {

            mLEScanner!!.stopScan(this)
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DEVICES_NONE_FOUND)
        }

    }
}
```

He intentado crear una lista de BluetoothDevices en la que ir añadiendo los resultados del escaneado:

```
val mLeDevices: MutableList<BluetoothDevice>?= null
```

y en el scancallback

```
mLeDevicesList.add(mLeDevice!!)
```

Pero al contar los elementos de ésta con:

```
mLeDevicesList.count()
```

Me retorna un null.

De manera que, en resumen, tengo dos cuestiones. 
¿El resultado del escaneado de startScan(mScanCallback) se guarda en alguna lista que desconozco o existe alguna manera de obtener estos resultados de forma que no sea individual?
En caso de que la anterior pregunta tenga una respuesta negativa, ¿Cómo crear una lista propia de la que posteriormente pueda obtener todos los resultados del escaneado?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Debes obtener los dispositivos individualmente y agregarlos a una lista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un problema que noto es que estas obteniendo únicamente dispositivos llamados "Running Speed" o  "EnvSens_Wearable",

```
  if(mLeDevice?.name == "Running Speed" || mLeDevice?.name == "EnvSens_Wearable"){
         //Obtiene dispositivos
  } else {
            mLEScanner!!.stopScan(this)
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DEVICES_NONE_FOUND)
   }
```

recuerda que en ocasiones los dispositivos no tienen un nombre registrado.

```
D/MainActivity: onScanResult: 8C:2D:AA:4E:73:D6 - BOSE 145
D/MainActivity: onScanResult: 5A:0F:5A:08:C8:90 - null
D/MainActivity: onScanResult: 51:FD:88:2F:A8:CD - null
D/MainActivity: onScanResult: 2C:41:A1:0F:C3:69 - LE-Bose Color I SoundLink
D/MainActivity: onScanResult: D0:03:4B:3F:BD:5C - null
D/MainActivity: onScanResult: 66:3F:16:F7:6A:BB - null
D/MainActivity: onScanResult: A0:9E:1A:29:A5:C6 - null
D/MainActivity: onScanResult: A0:9E:1A:29:A5:C6 - Xoom Z12
D/MainActivity: onScanResult: A0:9E:1A:29:A5:C6 - null
D/MainActivity: onScanResult: F8:77:B8:41:B7:0A - [TV] UN75J6300
```

---

Para obtener los dispositivos conectados es muy importante los permisos:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

y requerir el permiso `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` manualmente para dispositivos con sistema operativo mayor a 6.0

> ¿El resultado del escaneado de startScan(mScanCallback) se guarda en
>   alguna lista que desconozco o existe alguna manera de obtener estos
>   resultados de forma que no sea individual?

no puedes obtener una lista, pero puedes obtener todos los elementos y agregarlos a una lista, aunque recuerda que la lista cambia ya que se pueden conectar/dispositivos regularmente.

de esta forma puedes escanear los dispositivos y agregarlos a una lista:

```
   //Define lista para agregar dispositivos.
   val deviceList = ArrayList<String>()

    private val mScanCallback = object : ScanCallback() {
        override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult?) {
            super.onScanResult(callbackType, result)

            if("Dispositivo: ${result?.device?.address} - ${result?.device?.name}" in deviceList) {
                //Dispositivo ya se encuentra en lista
            }else {
                //Agrega dispositivo a lista.
                deviceList.add("Dispositivo: ${result?.device?.address} - ${result?.device?.name}")
            }
        }

    }
```

y de esta forma puedes obtener los dispositivos sin problema:

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la velocidad y efectividad de la respuesta, la he puesto en práctica con unos pequeños ajustes y ha funcionado a la primera! Tengo un apunte que añadir, anoche buscando en la api de android encontré una función conocida cómo onBatchScanResult (también en el scancallback) que en su argumento tiene una lista en la que en teoría se vuelca el escaneado. Por si alguien en algún momento se viese en la misma situación y buscase una alternativa, aunque lo dicho, ésta solución funciona perfectamente.De nuevo muchas gracias por tu tiempo.